# Android 4.1 default browser renders HTML page in a strange way

Tags: android, html, ruby-on-rails, android-browser

We got a login form, gently produced by Rails. But when we access the website from Galaxy S3 and it is accessed first time (or caches are clear), the page does not render fully. Instead, the bottom part of the page is being cut.

Yet, if i focus on one of input elements (or i tap the place where it should be, at least), page renders correctly.

Here are the examples on how the page looks when first entered and how it should look like:

[image]
[image]

**So, the question is:** can i force page redraw with javascript or there's something wrong with my page?

Comment: have you tried to validate it with w3 validator?

Comment: @fotanus removed all the errors, but the result is the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed replacing the form container' HTML instead of showing/hiding blocks with different forms.

E. g., we had two blocks for login and sign up forms. And on *sign in* button click *"sign in"* block showed and *"sign up"* block was hidden. And over against. So i just replaced the *show* / *hide* methods with HTML replacement:

```
$('.form-container').html($('.sign-in-form').html())
```

or

```
$('.form-container').html($('.sign-up-form').html())
```